# Failed to connect to Cisco anyconnect VPN via openconnect

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, connection, cisco

I've read several texts about this on the web and this site but couldn't solve the issue.I have `network-manager-openconnect` and `network-manager-vpnc` plugins installed on Ubuntu 14.04 (for GUI usage). To connect to a Cisco anyconnect VPN server all I have is **server IP**, **username** and **password**. Nothing as "**Group**" is given. However the "Group" isn't required as credential in openconnect, It's only asked through Cisco compatible VPN (VPNC).

Trying to connect using `openconnect`, After password submission the GUI encounters error and is closed quickly. Here is the log:

```
NetworkManager[1039]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openconnect'...
NetworkManager[1039]: <info> VPN service 'openconnect' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openconnect), PID 8432
NetworkManager[1039]: <info> VPN service 'openconnect' appeared; activating connections
NetworkManager[1039]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
NetworkManager[1039]: <error> [1422573707.651651] [nm-vpn-connection.c:1335] plugin_need_secrets_cb(): (b084369e-c287-42b1-9d5a-6f455d31b07c/Openconnect) final secrets request failed to provide sufficient secrets
NetworkManager[1039]: <info> Policy set 'SSID' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
NetworkManager[1039]:    keyfile: updating /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Cisco Annyconnect
NetworkManager[1039]: <info> VPN service 'openconnect' disappeared
```

I don't have the secret it mentioned. What's the problem?

Thanks